# A library of constexpr C++11 arrays, maps, tuples etc

Tags: library, software-development, c++

I need to do some `constexpr` work - in C++11. The standard library for that version of the language has most constructs with non-`constexpr` methods (either because they just weren't marked or because marking them `constexpr` would require code changes).

Is there a header-only, FOSS library of C++11-implemented constexpr versions of `std::array`, `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::pair` and `std::tuple`?